# Exception list for BING spelling check

Tags: bing

Currently, our site uses BING spelling check to correct our search.

However, when searching "medical suppliers", BING decides to change it to "medical supplies", which is not the term we uses in our system.

Using just the word - suppliers, BING doesn't change it to suppliers. It seems that BING only changes it in the context of medical suppliers.

Is there any way to tell BING to check the spelling of the word individually, and not worrying about the context?

Comment: When I just try "medical suppliers" on their [sample page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/spell-check/), it seems to pick up no errors in spell checking (in the JSON).  When I try "medical suppliers dfsdf", it claims "suppliers" is an "UnknownToken".

Comment: as a caveat, I realized that I was in "proof" mode versus "spell" mode.  In "spell" mode, it also flags suppliers in "medical suppliers".

Comment: Thank you. I will try proof (the less aggressive) mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have search experience on your site, you can have experience similar to Bing.com. It says including results for "Medical Supplies" and provides an option to search for "Medical Suppliers" only. Using "spell" mode is correct in this case. [image: Snapshot from Bing.com]

Comment: This is what I do in the company site, but the other department is not happy with it.